# Nested_form_fields show existing has_many nested fields upon validation failure

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I am using the [nested_form_fields gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nested_form_fields/0.7.4).  I have the following associations to allow a `contact` to have associations to multiple `teams`:

```
#models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :contacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts_teams, allow_destroy: true
end

#models/contacts_team.rb
class ContactsTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :team
end

#models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts_team
  has_many :contacts, through: :contacts_teams
end
```

A contact **always** Must have at least one `team`.  I created a custom validation which checks for this when the user is creating a new `contact` or is updating an existing `contact`.

```
#custom validation within models/contact.rb
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validate :at_least_one_contacts_team

  private
  def at_least_one_contacts_team
    # when creating a new contact: making sure at least one team exists
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Team" unless contacts_teams.length > 0

    # when updating an existing contact: Making sure that at least one team would exist
    return errors.add :base, "Must have at least one Team" if contacts_teams.reject{|contacts_team| contacts_team._destroy == true}.empty?
  end           
end
```

It works for the most part. But there is an edge case when updating an existing contact's team.  Here I am updating a contact and it shows that they have two existing associated teams:

[image: existing teams]

The user clicks the X's next to each team in order to delete them, so they no longer show on the page, and then the user clicks update to put these changes into effect:

[image: clicks the x's next to each contact]

[image: associated teams marked for deletion and don't show]

[image: submits changes]

The validation properly fails because the user attempted to delete all the associated teams.  It properly shows the validation error message:

[image: error message]

However, the problem is that the form does not redisplay the existing associated teams!  Those associations have not been deleted yet, so they should still show:

[image: Not showing existing team associations after validation fails]

**How do I show existing team associations after validations fail when updating an existing contact?**

I attempted removing all the `_destroy` flags in hopes that by doing so those associated teams will show.  Unfortunately it didn't do the trick:

```
# block run when update validation fails
else
  params[:contact][:contacts_teams_attributes].each do |k,v|
    v.delete_if{|k,v| k == "_destroy" && v == "1"}
  end
  render :edit
end
```

I am thinking that the page is remembering the nested_form_fields' javascript that was previously run.  So it remembers that the teams were marked to be deleted, therefore it is not rendering them.  I don't know how to reset the javascript unless I do a `redirect`, in which case all the validation errors will no longer be shown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could submit the form through ajax and just replace the teams section if there are errors, or alternatively render a javascript template as a response in the update method in your controller that does the same thing - re renders just the section of the page with the team select boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.  I changed the name of the custom validation within the `Contact` model so that the error message would make sense:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts_teams, allow_destroy: true
  validate :at_least_one_contacts_team

  private

  def at_least_one_contacts_team
    return errors.add :A_Team, "must be present" unless contacts_teams.length > 0
    return errors.add :A_Team, "must be present" if contacts_teams.reject{|contacts_team| contacts_team._destroy == true}.empty?
  end
end
```

And then within the `update` action of the `ContactsController`:

```
def update
  authorize @contact
  if @contact.update(contact_params)
    redirect_to(some_path), success: 'Updated Successfully.'
  else
    # This next line is what makes it work as expected for that edge case
    @contact.contacts_teams.reload if @contact.errors.keys.include?(:A_Team)
    render :edit
  end
end
```